# Android display data like the Guardian app

Tags: android

I'm looking for a simple example of how to display data on a screen in the same way the Guardian app does (including the image on the left) that I'm pulling from a php page as shown in the screen shot below. I just can't find any examples on the internet that fit this description.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guardian&hl=en

Sorry for what might seem like a simple question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these should help.

On stackoverflow, amongst others:
[SO - ListView and images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616971/listview-and-images), which also links to 
 [SO - Lazy loading of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

External:
[vogella.com - Android ListView and ListActivity - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) 
[Ben's blog - Lazy loading of images in Listview](http://negativeprobability.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-listview.html)