# How to add a sub item in Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have made a android listView taking the help from [Vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) using following layout and ListActivity class.

**RowLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="22px"
        android:layout_height="22px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MyListActivity.java**

```
package de.vogella.android.listactivity;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2" };
    // use your own layout
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

I want to add a sub item below the textView and keep the full text portion in the center of each row. How can I do it?

Comment: use [ExpandableList](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129) instead of ListView to create list with subitems

Comment: add another textview below First text view in your RowLayout.xml

Comment: @CrazyLearner Its better you should go with the `SectionListView` if you want to add the sub items for each items.

Comment: @JigarPandya , Yes I have done that, but How can I add that in the adapter?

Comment: @CrazyLearner: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92 -- It is an example according to your requirement.Hope it helps you

Comment: @CrazyLearner Check out my answer which will surely help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3617019/

Answer (score 30):

You can use the built-in android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 to create two line textView.

[image]

Comment: This should have been accepted instead as it solves the problem way more concisely.

Answer (score -1):

In order to add sub items to your items in List View, Use Expandable List View.

Have a look at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) example.

You can ask if you have any further queries :)

Comment: I don't want to make expandable list view, What I want is to display two textViews at a time in a row

Comment: Link doesn't work for me